# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException error in mvn clean for a play project

Tags: java, sbt

I am getting the following error when I try mvn clean install on a play project:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Position.start on class scala.reflect.internal.util.OffsetPosition
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.Position.start(Position.scala:114)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser.sbt$internals$parser$SbtParser$$convertStatement$1(SbtParser.scala:148)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser$$anonfun$4.apply(SbtParser.scala:153)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser$$anonfun$4.apply(SbtParser.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser.splitExpressions(SbtParser.scala:153)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser.<init>(SbtParser.scala:58)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.splitExpressions(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:226)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.parseConfiguration(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:69)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:106)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:789)
...
```

My sbt version is 0.13.18.
Here's how my ~/.sbt/repositories file looks like:

```
❯ cat ~/.sbt/repositories
[repositories]
  local
  sbt-releases-repo: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

Anyone knows how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Is the error message full? it seems there is something missing in the stack trace~

Comment: Unsupported Operation usually means that it isn't implemented in that class, and calling that method is hardcoded to throw that Exception. You may need to find the correct class of which to create an instance to call that method on

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov I have intentionally put only the top part of the stack trace so that the question is short. Let me know if I need to provide the full stack trace.